# Eclipse Android layout designer - add new screen sizes for previewing

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, eclipse-adt

The graphical layout designer in the Eclipse ADT includes the ability to preview how the layout will look on a variety of screen sizes/resolutions.  My question - is it possible to add new custom screen sizes to this list, to accommodate new devices when they come out?  If so, how?

Comment: I would suggest, if you haven't already, to update your ADT. Google keeps adding some new features to their ADT which are very helpful which include a feature that you describing.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Window -> Android Virtual Device Manager -> Device Definitions Tab -> New Device

Once you fill out all the properties, it should be an available option in the layout editor.

**Edit:** Restarting Eclipse/ADT may be required, as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Many thanks, had to restart Eclipse before my new device was visible in the layout designer but all working now.

Comment: I needed to restart Eclipse. (ADT Build: v21.1.0-569685)

Comment: This is a terrific answer. I +1ed it. I'm still stumped on how to get it to include the ICS/Jellybean menu (with the home button) in the preview. I set the AVD for the right Android version, but it's not showing up. What am I overlooking?

Comment: @Dr.Dredel Which menu are you referring to? The navigation  (Back/Home/Recent softkeys) can be enabled by checking the Navigation option on the Device States area.

Comment: works perfectly..was able to do 13 inch screen. and YES, you must restart

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible and you need to follow the next steps:

1. You start by defining a new **device defininition** with the specs that you want: Windows -> Android Virtual Device Manager -> Device Definitions Tab (New Device);
2. Then you will see that in your layout editor when choosing the device to render the layout for, you will have 3 categories: **Generic**, **Google** and **User**
3. Furthermore, you can add this device to your devices list for layout rendering by using *Manual Previews* and *Add as thumbnail* when your device is selected for rendering.

Answer (score 1):

there is another .
just change the device from the xml editor -> generic -> Tablet 7.0 /Tablet 10.0 .
that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the new version of the ADT plugin  you can't do it, but if your version is other one you can watch this question, it can helps you [ScrollView - How to scroll down while designing layout in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007489/scrollview-how-to-scroll-down-while-designing-layout-in-eclipse)